# Copiar registro dentro da mesma tabela, alterando alguns campos

Tags: vba

Estou tentando copiar um registro da tabela para um novo registro alterando alguns campos, mas ainda assim esta com erro e não consigo localizar, é possível ver aonde eu cometi o engano, segue abaixo as linhas de programação.

```
Dim strQtde As Integer, I As Byte
On Error GoTo Erro
        If MsgBox("Confirma copia do registro?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Atenção!") = True Then            Set rsMov = currentdb.OpenRecordset("DEVOLUÇÕES1")
            For I = 1 To strQtde
                rsMov.AddNew
                    rsMov("Aluno") = Me. Aluno
                    rsMov("Série") = Me. Série
                    rsMov("N_Tombo") = Me. N_Tombo
                    rsMov("Livro") = Me. Livro
                    rsMov("Data Retirada") =DateAdd("m", I, Me. Data Retirada)
                    rsMov("Data Dev") =DateAdd("m", I, Me. Data Dev)
                    rsMov("Periodo") = Me. Periodo
                    rsMov("Situação") = Me. Situação
                    rsMov("Penalidade Até") = Me. Penalidade Até
                    rsMov("PENALIDADE") = Me. PENALIDADE
                    rsMov("Observação") = Me. Observação
                    rsMov("Telefone") = Me. Telefone
                    rsMov("Celular") = Me. Celular
                    rsMov("RETIRADA") = Me. RETIRADA
                    rsMov("CONSULTA") = Me. CONSULTA
                    rsMov("Livros_") = Me. Livros_
                    rsMov("Revista") = Me. Revista
                    rsMov("TCC") = Me. TCC
                    rsMov("Outros") = Me. Outros
                    rsMov("Renovação") = Me. Renovação
                    rsMov("EMAIL") = Me. EMAIL
                    rsMov("Ficha    ") = Me. Ficha
                    rsMov("Data do Cadastro") = Me. Data do Cadastro
                    rsMov.Update
            Next I
            MsgBox "Registro renovado com sucesso.", vbInformation, strTitulo & strVersao
           Set rsMov = Nothing
        Else
            MsgBox "Operação cancelada.", vbInformation, "Atenção!!"
            Exit Sub
        End If

Sai:
    Set rsMov = Nothing
    Exit Sub
Erro:
    MsgBox "Erro ao renovar título.", vbInformation, "Atenção!!"
    Resume Sai
```

O sistema diz que falta um IF, peço ajuda por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Mauro, a linha do IF está com comandos após o THEN, ou seja, esse IF termina nesta mesma linha, por isso o END IF abaixo não reconhecer este IF.

Para solucionar o problema, passe a parte posterior ao THEN para a linha de baixo, como fiz na parte de código a seguir. É isso:

```
    If MsgBox("Confirma copia do registro?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Atenção!") = True Then 

     Set rsMov = currentdb.OpenRecordset("DEVOLUÇÕES1")

     ...
     ...
     ...
```

Comment: Oi Mauro, a resposta serviu para você amigo? Se sim, por favor, marque a resposta.